# Cannot get correct value from EJS template via javascript

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am busy with a website and want to use AJAX to load data after the page has been loaded. I am using an EJS template to display user data data and link a javascript file in the EJS template. In the EJS template I want to set checkboxes according to data from the database. I tried various ways to get the correct userID from the template to then load the relevant data from the database. When I display the userID directly on the template it shows the correct id, but when I do an alert from the javascript file it show the same id (the id from the first template) for all the templates. How can I get the correct id for each iteration/template?

The EJS template file:

```
<article class="post-item" id="<%= user.UserID %>" data-userId="<%= user.UserID %>">
  <p><span id="">
      <%= user.Email %>
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenField" id="userid" name="userid" value="<%= user.UserID %>" required>
      <p><%= user.UserID %></p>
        <% for (const cat of categories) { %>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="<%= cat.CategoryID %>" value="<%= cat.CategoryID %>">
            <label for="<%=cat.CategoryID %>"><%= cat.CategoryName %></label>
          </p>
          <% } %>
    </span></p>
</article>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/usercategories.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

The javascript file:

```
async function fetchUserCategories() {
    let hidden = document.querySelector(".hiddenField");
    let article = document.querySelector(".post-item");
    //alert('USerID = ' + article.dataset.userId)
    alert('USerID = ' + hidden.value)

    }

fetchUserCategories();
```

Part of the main EJS page:

```
<% if (!users || users.length===0) { %>
    <p>No users found!</p>
    <% } else { %>
        <ol id="posts-list">
            <% for (const user of users) { %>
                <li>
                    <%- include('includes/actor-item', { user: user, categories: categories }) %>
                </li>
                <% } %>
        </ol>
        <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `document.querySelector()` to select the classes `.hiddenField` & `.post-item`. But the `document.querySelector()` only returns the first element that matches the selector. [Docs: querySelector() method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

That means when you run your `fetchUserCategories()` with the querySelector you will get `.hiddenField` & `.post-item` but only the first item that matches. That's why its why you only see the first item multiple times because that is the only one you have picked up.
To fix this you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()`[Docs: querySelectorAll() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) so instead of separate items you will get a list/array of items that matches the ones you are searching for.

And then you can loop it through.

So your `fetchUserCategories ()` will look like this:

```js
async function fetchUserCategories() {
  let hiddenFields = document.querySelectorAll(".hiddenField");
  let articleItems = document.querySelectorAll(".post-item");

  for (let i = 0; i < hiddenFields.length; i++) {
    let hidden = hiddenFields[i];
    let article = articleItems[i];

    alert('UserID = ' + hidden.value);

    // Rest of your logic here with current hidden and article elements
  }
}
```